# RecyclerView not visible

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

I have this code in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainViewInterface{

RecyclerView rvMovies;

private String TAG = "MainActivity";
MoviesAdapter adapter;
MainPresenter mainPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupMVP();
    mainPresenter.getMovies();

    rvMovies = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvMovies.setLayoutManager(manager);
    //rvMovies.setHasFixedSize(true);
}

private void setupMVP() {

    mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this);

}



@Override
public void showToast(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void displayMovies(MovieResponse moviesResponse) {

    if(moviesResponse!=null) {
        Log.d(TAG,moviesResponse.getResults().get(1).getTitle());
        adapter = new MoviesAdapter(moviesResponse.getResults(), MainActivity.this);
        rvMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG,"Movies response null");
    }

}

@Override
public void displayError(String s) {
    showToast(s);
  }
}
```

But I get this

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

I know other people asked the same question. I tried their solutions but didn't work. What am I missing?

This is my adapter code.

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MoviesHolder> {
List<Result> movieList;
Context context;

public MoviesAdapter(List<Result> movieList, Context context){
    this.movieList = movieList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MoviesHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_movies,parent,false);
    MoviesHolder mh = new MoviesHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( MoviesHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tvTitle.setText(movieList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvOverview.setText(movieList.get(position).getOverview());
    holder.tvReleaseDate.setText(movieList.get(position).getReleaseDate());
    Glide.with(context).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"+movieList.get(position).getPosterPath()).into(holder.ivMovie);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieList.size();
}

public class MoviesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvTitle,tvOverview,tvReleaseDate;
    ImageView ivMovie;

    public MoviesHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvOverview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOverView);
        tvReleaseDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReleaseDate);
        ivMovie = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivMovie);
    }
  }
```

Thanks,
Theo.

**SOLVED**

In my activivity_main.xml I had both height and with equal to 0dp!!! I honestly don't know how and who put those values in!! That's why the recycler view was not visible!!!

Comment: share your adapter code

Comment: log and verify whether displayMovies() is being called or not... log another inside if(moviesRespose!=null) also

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod. i added the adapter code.

Comment: @Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(moviesResponse.getResults().size())); That returns me 20. So displaysMovies() method is being called.

Comment: try this: create and initialize an instance variable of array of whatever object the getResults() returns...then initialize your adapter in onCreate() and pass it the instance variable u just created of the array, now call instanceVariable of array = moviesResponse.getResults() ....and call notifyDataSetChanged() in displayMovies()

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call `rvMovies.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(new ArrayList<>()))` on your RecyclerView during `onCreate` - there is nothing bad about setting an empty (from items perspective) adapter on RecyclerView, it will simply show an empty list. Then once you have your data ready (downloaded/loaded from any source you are loading from) you will simply call something like `adapter.setItems(newItemsList)` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Also one more note: you should not store `Context` in class member fields as leaks might occur (I am pretty sure your Android Studio must complain about that as well in a form of a Lint Warning check). You actually don't even need that `Context` instance passing to your adapter as you can simply retrieve a `Context` instance from `parent` View in `onCreateViewHolder` - rewrite it like this:

```
@Override
public MoviesHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_movies,parent,false);
    MoviesHolder mh = new MoviesHolder(v);
    return mh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupMVP();

    rvMovies = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvMovies.setLayoutManager(manager);
    rvMovies.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mainPresenter.getMovies();  <== put this line in last
}
```

Comment: can you post activity_main xml

Comment: rvMovies.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

These 2 lines:

```
setupMVP();
mainPresenter.getMovies();
```

must be written after:

```
rvMovies = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);
```

Comment: I am stupid. In activity_main.xml I had layout_height and layout_widht equal to 0dp!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set adapter after you set the views.

```
rvMovies = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
rvMovies.setLayoutManager(manager);
//rvMovies.setHasFixedSize(true);
//call after setting the view
mainPresenter.getMovies();
```